# c# convert PDF metadata CreationTime to DateTime

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to process the CreationTime I retrieve from the PDF's metadata and compare it to DataTime format.

```
string path = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(path);
var CreatedDate = pdfReader.Info["CreationDate"];
e.Row.Cells[13].Text = Convert.ToString(CreatedDate);
```

This returns a Date-Time-String like:

- D:20150710080410
- D:20150209075651+01'00'

and to compare:

```
            DateTime Created = Convert.ToDateTime(CreatedDate);
            DateTime Compare = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[14].Text);
            if (Compare > Created)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[15].Text = "actualizar";
            }
```

Martin

Comment: so what is the question and where are you doing this `compare` of the metadata to datetime...?

Comment: Those date-time strings look exactly as described in ISO-32000-1, so... yes, they look OK. Why do you think they are wrong?

Comment: Ok, I didn't knew this was standard - sorry for my ignorance - So the question would be how to convert this to a compatible format in order to compare the data to a DateTime column I retrieve from the gridview (displayed like 21/07/2015 7:24:54). See above in my edited post.This throws an error converting Convert.ToDateTime(CreatedDate) to DateTime. The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

I really needed a solution for this, BBL Admin 's Comment on writing your own function turned out to be my way out.

From this [this itex support link][1] I was able to get the intepratation of the pdfDate format as **D:YYYYMMDDHHmmSSOHH'mm'**

Next thing I needed to know is the supportade date formats in **c#** that I may Parse using `DateTime.Parse()` from [this c-sharpcorner artical][2] and the most ideal for me was **"yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss"**

Having known the input I get and the format I can parse, I created the function below to construct the date, basically getting parts from the pdfDate and building parts for the 'parsable' date string...

```
private DateTime CreateDateTime(string date) //use the pdfDate as parameter to the date argument
  {
            string dateStr = date.Remove(0, 2).Remove(14, 6); //Remove D: & OHH'mm
            string tmpDateStr = dateStr.Substring(0, 4) //Get year i.e yyyy
                + "-" + dateStr.Substring(4, 2) // Get month i.e mm & prepend - (hyphen)
                + "-" + dateStr.Substring(6, 2) // Get day i.e dd & prepend -
                + "T" + dateStr.Substring(8, 2) // Get hour and prepend T
                + ":" + dateStr.Substring(10, 2) // Get minutes and prepend :
                + ":" + dateStr.Substring(12, 2); //Get seconds and prepend :

            return DateTime.Parse(tmpDateStr);  
  }
```

Well, I hope you found a way at the time of asking, anyone else facing the same challange could try my approach and see if it helps. Nevertheless, question answered.

**NB:** There could be other/better ways to do it.
[1]: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/7.1.0/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDate.html
[2]: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: .Remove(14, 6) seems not require,  and it may throw error if length is not up to 14 char.
Btw your ans help me out

Answer (score 0):

If your Date-Time string that you're trying to convert is going to start with "D:" every time, then you might think about adding in a remove function for D:.  That's what's probably giving you the exception when you try to convert.  Try this:

```
// Gather the Info
string path = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(path);
var CreatedDate = pdfReader.Info["CreationDate"];
e.Row.Cells[13].Text = Convert.ToString(CreatedDate);
string sCreatedDate = Convert.ToString(CreatedDate).Remove(0, 2)

// Convert and Compare
DateTime Created = Convert.ToDateTime(sCreatedDate);
DateTime Compare = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[14].Text);
if (Compare > Created)
{
    e.Row.Cells[15].Text = "actualizar";
}
```

You don't have to create sCreatedDate, but it's a little bit cleaner to view it that way.  You could also convert CreatedDate.ToString().Remove(0,2) when you do the datetime convert:

```
DateTime Created = Convert.ToDateTime(CreatedDate.ToString().Remove(0,2));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't! The conversion throws again the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Can you post what sCreateDate is equal to when doing the conversion?

Comment: hmmm... just by eliminating the leading 2 characters the string is not converted into something more digestible for the Convert.ToDateTime command: Convert.ToDateTime("20150710080410") -> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: Sorry, I've been away for a while.  I did some digging on valid DateTime formats and it is indeed not a valid format.  For example:  20150710080410 is not valid, but this is the valid format:  **2015-07-10T08:04:10**.  Similary:  **20150209075651+01'00'** is not valid, but **2015-02-09T07:56:51+01:00** will convert.  See this link:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might need a method to return the right value so you can do a comparison.  Is the value you are needing to convert in a standardized format?  If so this should be fairly easy to accomplish.